# Mavericks."AFP error -1 mapped to EIO" error on console - sharing is unilateral

Tags: macos, network, afp

When I try to connect (cmd-k) to my MacBook Pro from my Mac Mini - using "afp://name.local" or the IP instead of the name, I get an error logged to console

> AFP error -1 mapped to EIO

I can connect the reverse way, from MacBook Pro to Mac Mini and both run Mavericks.

Both on the same network. Used to work in the past. Any clues?